# Posix Semaphore => how to close a semaphore after a while. Producers - Consumers Problem

Tags: c, semaphore, producer-consumer

I am reading files by produces and writing them to the other files by consumers and when the input files are read by the producers I need to close one of the semaphore and consumers do not wait any more for producers for inserting some new input to buffer. Is there any way to do that?

Regards...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few possibilities:

- use a flag that indicates the producer is done.  Consumers who unblock from the semaphore need to check that flag and clean up when it's set. When the producer sets the flag, it can signal the semaphore enough times to release any possible consumers. You need to take care to deal with a race condition where something is queued for consumption, but the 'producer done' flag is set before a consumer gets past checking the flag. This can possibly be handled easily if you let the consumer threads go ahead and try to dequeue a work item, but have them cleanly handle a situation where there's nothing to do even though the semaphore was signaled. *Then* have them look at the 'producer done' flag.
- use `pthread_kill()` to send a signal to any waiting consumers.  This should kick them out of the `sem_wait()`, where they can check for the `EINTR` return code.  This also would need to be coded carefully to avoid races. I'm not particularly familiar with POSIX signal handling, but I'm sure it comes with its own set of baggage that you need to be very careful in handling correctly.
- switch to using condition variables with mutexes where you can check for the queue state and the done condition atomically while holding the mutex.

Of course, once that's been done someone (the producer thread?) needs to wait for all the consumer threads to clean up - probably by doing a `pthread_join()` on them - before the semaphore is destroyed/closed.

The condition variable option is probably a bigger change if you already have something coded up using semaphores, and it might not be as performant in the normal case when are being produced and consumed (maybe).  But I'd bet that it's easier to reason about the possible race conditions and handle them correctly. Note that I don't say it's easy, just that it might be easier.